# Math.max for this function

Tags: javascript

I need to create an HTML page, add three text boxes in which the user will input three numbers: `a`, `b`, `c`.

Then I'll have a button that, on click, will calculate the maximum number of the three. The result will be displayed in an alert. The program should not crash if the user does not input one or two numbers.

Cases:

- If no number is introduced then a message should be displayed asking the user to input at least one number.
- If only one number of the three is introduced, that number is the maximum number.
- If two numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the two.
- If three numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the three.

I get `NaN` alert popup, but I need an alert displaying `"input at least one number"`. This is what I've tried:

```js
function max() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);
  var max = 0;

  var end = Math.max(a, b, c) || Math.max(a, b) || Math.max(a) || Math.max(a, c) || Math.max(b, c);


  alert(end);

  nbs = [a, b, c].filter(nb => !isNaN(nb));

  if (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)) {
    alert("Input at least one number");
  } else {
    console.log(Math.max(nbs));
  }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: `Math.max(a, b, c)` should be enough to calculate the max, why the other 4?

Comment: if i use `Math.max(a, b, c); ` i get an alert `NaN` if i input 1 or 2 number this is why i use the rest but if i  don't enter any number i will get `NaN` insted of " Input at least one number"

Comment: Ahh yeah, you should be checking that

Comment: `var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value)||0;` to prevent the breaking `null`

Comment: @dandavis, that would only work if negative numbers are not expected/allowed. Leny, could you update the question to clarify if that's the case? How would you like negative numbers to be handled? Note, as well, that `parseInt` may not be ideal if, for example, the user is able to enter a string that begins with a number, e.g. `parseInt("8s")===8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the best results when using `|| 0` after the value assignment. This ensures that `a`, `b`, and `c` get a value. then you can take out all the or `Math.max` when finding `end`. Here is a code snippet with that:

```js
function max(){
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) || 0;
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value) || 0;
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value) || 0;

    var end = Math.max(a, b, c);

    if (a === 0 && b === 0 && c === 0) {
    alert("Input at least one number");
  } else {
    alert(end);
  }
}

var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.addEventListener('click', () => max());
```

```html
  <div><input type="text" id="num1"></div>
  <div><input type="text" id="num2"></div>
  <div><input type="text" id="num3"></div>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

If you think the user should be able to insert negative numbers just change `0` to `-100000` (or whatever negative number you deem appropriate). Hope this helps.

Furthermore, if you would like to have a more dynamic way of doing this you could do this very efficiently by getting all the inputs with `querySelectorAll` and using `Array.prototype.reduce()` to separate your values out and push them to a new array. Then you can just return the maximum value from that. Here is an example of that:

```js
function max() {
  const nums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.num')].reduce((i, v) => {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(v.value))) i.push(v.value);
    return i;
  }, []);
  return nums.length ? Math.max(...nums) : 'input at least one number';
}


document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', () => alert(max()));
```

```html
<div><input class="num" type="text"></div>
<div><input class="num" type="text"></div>
<div><input class="num" type="text"></div>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This is working for me. ty 4 this code . i can't upvote you couse i just join this forum . Ty again .

Comment: @LenyLestter I'm surprised with the accepted answer... I wonder what happens when you want five `input` boxes instead of three...

Comment: @Ivan I've updated my answer to include a more dynamic way of doing this. This way he can have a thousand `input` boxes instead of three. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you can achieve this in a few lines of code:

- First select all `input` elements and have them in an array. Map them to an array of the input's values. All of them are passed through `parseInt()` whether they're integers or not:

  ```
  let nbs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.nb')].map(e => parseInt(e.value))
  ```
- then I filter them to only keep the ones that are integers. Careful because `typeof NaN == "number"` is true... So also make sure it's not `NaN`:

  ```
  let nbsF = nbs.filter(e => ( typeof e == "number" && !isNaN(e) ) )
  ```
- Finally return the result by checking if the array has at least one object (i.e. at least one number, because it has been filtered to only contain numbers). If the array doesn't contain any number, return a string:

  ```
  return nbsF.length ? Math.max(...nbsF) : 'input at least one number'
  ```

```js
let max = function() {

  let nbs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.nb')].map(e => parseInt(e.value))
  
  let nbsF = nbs.filter(e => ( typeof e == "number" && !isNaN(e) ) )
  
  return nbsF.length ? Math.max(...nbsF) : 'input at least one number'
  
}
```

```html
<input class="nb" type="text">
<input class="nb" type="text">
<input class="nb" type="text">

<button onclick="console.log(max())">Get maximum</button>
```

---

**For those interested:**

- I'm using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in the first part to convert the `NodeList` of `HTMLElement`s (provided by `document.querySelectorAll()`) into an actual object `Array` of `HTMLElement`s. This way I can use methods from the `Array` like [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- In the return statement, I am using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which is a shorcut for an `if...else` statement. In this case:

  ```
  return nbsF.length ? Math.max(...nbsF) : 'input at least one number'
  ```

  is equivalent to:

  ```
  if(nbsF.length) {
    return Math.max(...nbsF)
  } else {
    return 'input at least one number';
  }
  ```

  which is pretty handy to use.
- As [lucchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9871185/lucchi) said in the comments: instead of returning `nbsF.length ? Math.max(...nbsF) : 'input at least one number'`, we could:

  - first sort the array in ascending order with [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
  - return the last item of the array with [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

  So the return statement would be:

  ```
  return nbsF.sort().pop()
  ```

Comment: `return nbsF.sort().pop() || 'input at least one number'´

Comment: Indeed I didn't think of that, I have added it as an alternative. Thank you @lucchi for sharing.

Comment: It was just to point out the fact that there is no Math here ;)

Comment: Curious as to why you are using the `let` keyword? Are you planning on changing the `max` function or the `nbs` variable later? And also why you are using `var` right after this?

Comment: @CoryKleiser Are you getting picky? Why the downvote?

Comment: See previous comment. If you're going to use `const` and `let`, use them correctly and consistently.

Comment: @CoryKleiser, I think you and I got on the wrong foot. You answered the OP's question, and he has made the choice to accept your answer, that's fine. I was surprised and commented on your post to tell you that my solution seemed more "scalable". I'm sure that's not what the OP was looking for though. After seeing your comment and your edit with your 2nd code version, it seemed very inspired by my answer, you'll have to admit that... Anyway, that's not a problem but was quite surprised you would react like that. I hope you learned something from this. See you around. Ivan

Comment: @Ivan, Understandable. But this is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), so I believe my original answer was appropriate; which is why I was surprised by your comment. After that, I figured I'd add a "scalable" way of doing things and it does use elements of your answer, but it is more efficient to use `reduce` once than two separate calls to `map` and `filter`. I stand by my critique of your use of `let` though. Seems like you should be using `const`. But who am I to say. I'm no expert. No hard feelings on my side. Have a great day.

Comment: I usually have `let` in my code instead of `var`, this was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways, one is a brute force way one is another way.

```
function max(){
  var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var c=parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);
  var max = 0;

  if (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)) {
    alert("Input at least one number");
  }
  else if (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)) {
    alert(c);
  }
  else if (isNaN(a) && isNaN(c)) {
    alert(b);
  }
  else if (isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)) {
    alert(a);
  }
  else if (isNaN(a)) {
    alert(Math.max(b, c));
  }
  else if (isNaN(b)) {
    alert(Math.max(a, c));
  }
  else if (isNaN(c)) {
    alert(Math.max(a, b));
  }
  else {
    alert(Math.max(a, b, c));
  }

}
```

That would be the brute force way, which is the first way I thought of.

Instead of that, you could also do the same thing like this, in which you set a b and c to a really small number if it is null

```
function max(){
  var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value)||-10000;
  var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value)||-10000;
  var c=parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value)||-10000;
  var max = 0;

  var end = Math.max(a, b, c);

  if (end == -10000) {
    alert("Input at least one number");
  }
  else {
    alert(end);
  }


}
```

Comment: @LenyLestter No problem! Remember to upvote the answer and mark it as the correct answer ;)

Comment: i just join this forum . i have not enough reputation yet

Comment: Ok, you can still mark as correct answer though, just click the check mark next to this.